# angular6 cannot set the value of ngForm from component.ts

Tags: angular6

i am developing an basic angular 6 application that fetches the data, display it in the table, each row has delete, edit button this is one component 'detail list', i have another component as 'detail component' that are having controls to add the record in the table, i am fetching the data from the webapi, adding the record and deleting the record using the same webapi, they all are working fine, now i want to edit the record from the table, i am using the same webapi to fetch the data, webapi returning the record, i want to display this record's data in the 'detail component', the same component that is used to add the record, so at the component i am calling ngAfterViewInit()

>

```
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.service.change.subscribe((data: Patient) => {
    alert('in the detail component of ngAfterViewInit');
    console.log(data);
     this.ModelChange(data);
    }) ;
  }
```

and the code for the ModelChange is as follows

> ModelChange(data: Patient) {
>          this.form.controls['PatientCode'].setValue(data.PatientCode);

}

and my html is like

> 

```
<form #form="ngForm" autocomplete="on" (submit)="OnSubmit(form)">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group">
      <input name="PatientCode" [(ngModel)]="PatientCode"class="form-control" placeholder ="Patient Code"  (ngModelChange)="ModelChange(event)" required>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md -3 form-group">
          <input name="FirstName" [(ngModel)] ="FirstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" required>

      </div>
    <div class=" col-md-5 form-group">
        <input name="LastName" [(ngModel)]="LastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" required>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
          <input name="MRN" class="form-control"  [(ngModel)]="MRN" placeholder="MRN" required>

        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
            <!--<input name="DateOfBirth" class="form-control" placeholder="Date of Birth">-->
            <ejs-datepicker name="DateOfBirth" [(ngModel)]="DateOfBirth" id='datepicker' placeholder='Enter Date Of Birth' [value]='value' [min]='minDate' [max]='maxDate'></ejs-datepicker>

          </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
          <button type="submit" (click)="AddPatient(p)" class="btn btn-success center-block "> Add Patient</button>  
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-13">
        <button type="submit" (click)="EditPatient(p)" class="btn btn-success center-block "> Edit Patient</button>  
    </div>

    </div>
  </form>
```

at the console i am getting error that cannot Cannot read property 'controls' of undefined

Please help me out what is the correct way of setting the control property with the fetched data